# Match regular expression case insensitively, replace with specific case

Tags: regex, r

I'm using regular expressions to replace some substrings.  The replacement value reuses part of the match.  I want to match case insensitively, but in the replacement, I want a lower case version of the thing that was matched.

```
library(stringi)
x <- "CatCATdog"
rx <- "(?i)(cat)(?-i)"
stri_replace_all_regex(x, rx, "{$1}")
# [1] "{Cat}{CAT}dog"
```

This is close to what I want, except the "cat"s should be lower case.  That is, the output string should be `"{cat}{cat}dog"`.

The following code doesn't work, but it shows my intension.

```
stri_replace_all_regex(x, rx, "{tolower($1)}")
```

The following technique does work, but it's ugly, not very generalizable, and not very efficient.  My idea was to replace the regular expression with one that matches what I want, but not the replacement values (that is, "cat" but not "{cat}").  Then search for the first match in each input string, find the location of the match, do a substring replacement, then look for the next match until there are no more.  It's awful.

```
x <- "CatCATdog"
rx <- "(?i)((?<!\\{)cat(?!\\}))(?-i)"
repeat{
  detected <- stri_detect_regex(x, rx)
  if(!any(detected))
  {
    break
  }
  index <- stri_locate_first_regex(x[detected], rx)
  match <- tolower(stri_match_first_regex(x[detected], rx)[, 2])
  stri_sub(x[detected], index[, 1], index[, 2]) <- paste0("{", match[detected], "}")
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way.

How do I replace case insensitive matches with lower case values?

---

Thanks to inspiration from the comments, I discovered that the thing I'm looking for is "[replacement text case conversion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html)".

Comment: `gsub(rx, "{\\L\\1}", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @user2957945 sounds like an answer

Comment: @ThomasAyoub ; it was just a quick comment - im best to leave this to the regex ninjas incase of edge cases etc that i dont realise + Richie seems to want to use strtingi which i dont use.

Comment: @user2957945 It looks like `stringi` doesn't support case conversion, so you might as well write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\\L` to change the case of the match to lower

```
gsub(rx, "{\\L\\1}", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to perform any kind of string manipulation you may use [**`gsubfn`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html):

```
> library(gsubfn)
> rx <- "(?i)cat"
> s = "CatCATdog"
> gsubfn(rx, ~ paste0("{",tolower(x),"}"), s, backref=0)
[1] "{cat}{cat}dog"
```

You can use the `gsubfn` as you would use an anonymous callback method inside `String#replace` in JavaScript (you may specify the arguments for capturing groups with `function(args)`, and also make more sophisticated manipulations inside).

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the tilde operator' s function in the above example?

Comment: It is a placeholder telling `gsubfn`  that we only need to use the whole match text inside (accessed with `x`), just one default argument.