# escape all punctuation characters in R

Tags: r, regex, escaping

Consider having the string: `string<- "The qu!ck, brown fox jumps over the`lazy`d*g!"` and you wish to escape all punctuation. Thus:

```
escaped_string<-"The qu\\!ck\\, brown fox jumps over the \\`lazy\\` d\\*g"
```

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
>gsub(pattern = "[[:punct:]]",replacement="\\1",string)
[1] "The quck brown fox jumps over the lazy dg
```

Thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group and use

```
string <- "The qu!ck, brown fox jumps over the `lazy` d*g!"
gsub(pattern = "([[:punct:]])",replacement="\\\\\\1",string)
[1] "The qu\\!ck\\, brown fox jumps over the \\`lazy\\` d\\*g\\!"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/8V9uzg)

The pair of unescaped parentheses in `([[:punct:]])` creates a capturing group that you may access with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern. The replacement pattern should be defined as `"\\\\\\1"`, since to replace with a literal backslash you need to escape the literal backslash (thus, `"\\\\"` denotes one replacing backslash) and the backreference should be defined with `"\\1"` (also needs a literal backslash).

Comment: On a separate note how can one deduce the numbers of occurrence per regex case ? Imagine i want to substitute only two (next to each other) and more punctuations.

Comment: By substitute I mean I want to substitute with the *same number*  of occurrences. Hence **",,"-> "\\,\\,"** AND **"!!!"-> "\\!\\!\\!"**

Comment: You may use `gsubfn` package or use some base R code to cope with that task.  Here is [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450266/3832970) with `gsubfn`  example usage.

Comment: @agerom: Maybe [this R code sample](http://ideone.com/iJYust) will also be of help.