# Is the regex \\L supported in R 3.5.0?

Tags: r, regex

I am experiencing difficulty with the perl expression `\\L\\1` in very particular circumstances on R-dev (2017-06-06 and 2017-06-16 r72796 builds):

```
bib <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HughParsonage/TeXCheckR/master/tests/testthat/lint_bib_in.bib", encoding = "UTF-8")

leading_spaces <- 2

is_field <- grepl("=", bib, fixed = TRUE)
field_width <- nchar(trimws(gsub("[=].*$", "", bib, perl = TRUE)))

widest_field <- max(field_width[is_field])

out <- bib

# Vectorized gsub:
for (line in seq_along(bib)){
  # Replace every field line with
  # two spaces + field name + spaces required for widest field + space
  if (is_field[line]){
    spaces_req <- widest_field - field_width[line]
    out[line] <-
      gsub("^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*[=]\\s*\\{",
           paste0(paste0(rep(" ", leading_spaces), collapse = ""),
                  "\\L\\1",
                  paste0(rep(" ", spaces_req), collapse = ""),
                  " = {"),
           bib[line],
           perl = TRUE)
  }
}

# Add commas: 
out[is_field] <- gsub("\\}$", "\\},", out[is_field], perl = TRUE)

out[9]
#> R-dev   "  author"
#> R 3.4.0 "  author      = {Tony Wood and Amélie Hunter and Michael O'Toole and Prasana Venkataraman and Lucy Carter},"
```

To reproduce, it is necessary:

- To `readLines` from a file, and specify the encoding. (Using `dput` won't reproduce)
- To use `\\L` or `\\U` in the perl regex.
- To use a vector of characters
- To have an element of that vector that requires UTF-8 (é in Amélie in the above)

Is this a change in R 3.5.0, or have I been misusing `\\L` in this instance?

Comment: Look, you have been warned: [*It likely contains bugs, so be careful if you use it.*](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html).

Comment: I could not build the snippet - what is `leading_spaces`?

Comment: This particular bug is causing an error on an R CMD check for a package. Sorry about the nonreprex, I've edited.

Comment: Ok, why don't you just replace that with `gsubfn`? You do not really have to use `\L` with `gsub` (although it is easier, I admit). See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449416/match-regular-expression-case-insensitively-replace-with-specific-case/39450266#39450266).

Comment: I am still at a loss: what is the expected result here? Look at [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/IJVN7C/1), it matches `author`. Why turn it to lower case if it is already in lower case?

Comment: Well, it might not be. By way of background, the aim is to make author etc consistently lowercase, as well as aligning the equals signs.

Comment: Ok, have you tried with `gsubfn`? See https://ideone.com/SHOJZn (edited to use default R engine) (it does not work there, it is just the code I tried locally).

Comment: Take this to the R-devel mailing list. They can tell you what is intended and are grateful for bug reports. However, you should create a more minimal example.

Comment: Hugh, I just installed 3.5.0 and confirm `\L\1` does not work, but `gsubfn` solution works. Shall I post this work around? I cannot see another way here.

Comment: Yes please, it technically doesn't fully answer the question but it might nonetheless be the best solution for the background problem. Thank you! What `sessionInfo()` were you using out of interest?

Comment: @Roland thanks. I've emailed R-dev.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : You say that `\L` / `\l` / `\U` / `\u` were added to base R. As far as I can see `\L` and `\U` work (along with `\L`. But I didn't manage to make `\l` or `\u` work. Could you confirm that they should work with base R gsub ?

Comment: @Gilles: It just occurred logical to me that they should be also present there, but you are right, they do not seem supported. [`\l` and `\u` do not seem to work](https://ideone.com/LHeMe1) (test on R 3.3.2).

Comment: é does not require UTF-8 (or any other UTF or UCS encoding), it is also contained in single-byte encodings like ISO 8859-1 or Windows codepage 1252 (see the locale settings in @WiktorStribiżew's answer)

Comment: @Roland I emailed R-dev on 19 Jun but haven't heard back from them. Do you know if it usually takes this long for the email to clear moderation? Not offended, just wondering if I should try another approach.

Comment: It's cleared moderation ([see here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-June/074494.html)) and you can assume that R-core members have read it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, it is supported. The patch correcting this behaviour was applied in r74274.

```
Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 14:56:11 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] Fix lower/upper case conversions in UTF-8 in gsub (related to
 72714).

git-svn-id: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk@74274 00db46b3-68df-0310-9c12-caf00c1e9a41
---
 src/main/grep.c | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/src/main/grep.c b/src/main/grep.c
index dd10b9d923e..68e63616c87 100644
--- a/src/main/grep.c
+++ b/src/main/grep.c
@@ -1592,7 +1592,7 @@ char *pcre_string_adj(char *target, const char *orig, const char *repl,
            for (j = 0; j < nc; j++) wc[j] = towctrans(wc[j], tr);
            nb = (int) wcstoutf8(NULL, wc, INT_MAX);
            wcstoutf8(xi, wc, nb);
-           for (j = 0; j < nb; j++) *t++ = *xi++;
+           for (j = 0; j < nb - 1; j++) *t++ = *xi++;
            }
        } else
            for (i = ovec[2*k] ; i < ovec[2*k+1] ; i++) {
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**

> The patch correcting this behaviour was applied in r74274.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

There is clearly some unexpected behavior.

When referring to `\1`, it works outputting:

```
[1] "  author      = {Tony Wood and Amélie Hunter and Michael O'Toole and Prasana Venkataraman and Lucy Carter},"
```

However, whenever a `\U` or `\L` is used with `\1`,the second backreference gets removed.

- `"\\U\\1"`: `[1] "  AUTHOR"`
- `"\\U\\1\\E\\2"`: `[1] "  AUTHOR"`

A `gsubfn` solution still works (here, an example with `toupper()`):

```
library(gsubfn)
bib <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HughParsonage/TeXCheckR/master/tests/testthat/lint_bib_in.bib", encoding = "UTF-8")
leading_spaces <- 2
is_field <- grepl("=", bib, fixed = TRUE)
field_width <- nchar(trimws(gsub("[=].*$", "", bib, perl = TRUE)))
widest_field <- max(field_width[is_field])
out <- bib

# Vectorized gsub:
for (line in seq_along(bib)){
  # Replace every field line with
  # two spaces + field name + spaces required for widest field + space
  if (is_field[line]){
    spaces_req <- widest_field - field_width[line]
    out[line] <-
      gsubfn("^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*\\{", 
             function(y) paste0(
                  paste0(rep(" ", leading_spaces), collapse = ""),
                  toupper(y),
                  paste0(rep(" ", spaces_req), collapse = ""),
                  " = {"
             ),
           bib[line], engine="R"
      )
  }
}
# Add commas: 
out[is_field] <- gsub("\\}$", "},", out[is_field], perl = TRUE)

out[9]
```

Output:

```
[1] "  AUTHOR      = {Tony Wood and Amélie Hunter and Michael O'Toole and Prasana Venkataraman and Lucy Carter},"
```

My sessionInfo details:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2017-06-19 r72808)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gsubfn_0.6-6 proto_1.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    tcltk_3.5.0
```