# Regex to maintain matched parts

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to achieve this result : `"raster(B04) + raster(B02) - raster(A10mB03)"`
Therefore, I created this regex: `B[0-1][0-9]|A[1,2,6]0m/B[0-1][0-9]"`

I am now trying to replace all matches of the string `"B04 + B02 - A10mB03"` with `gsub("B[0-1][0-9]]|[A[1,2,6]0mB[0-1][0-9]", "raster()", string)`

How could I include the original values `B01, B02, A10mB03`?

PS: I also tried `gsub("B[0-1][0-9]]|[A[1,2,6]0mB[0-1][0-9]", "raster(\\1)", string)` but it did not work.

Comment: Try `gsub("(B[0-1][0-9]|A[1,2,6]0mB[0-1][0-9])", "raster(\\1)", string)`.

Comment: What's `string`?

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas. That worked.

Comment: `A[1,2,6]0m` will also match `A,0m`. Remove all `,`. BTW, you might also want to try [`gsub("(\\w+)", "raster(\\1)", "B04 + B02 - A10mB03")`](https://ideone.com/kHqJ7K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to match some text and re-use it inside a replacement pattern. In base R regex methods, there is no way to do that without a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), i.e. a pair of unescaped parentheses, enclosing the whole regex pattern in this case, and use a `\\1` [*replacement backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement pattern.

However, your regex contains some issues: `[A[1,2,6]` gets parsed as a single character class that matches `A`, `[`, `1`, `,`, `2` or `6` because you placed a `[` before `A`. Also, note that `,` inside character classes matches a literal comma, and it is not what you expected. Another, similar issue, is with `[0-9]]` - it matches any ASCII digit with `[0-9]` and then a `]` (the `]` char does not have to be escaped in a regex pattern).

So, a potential fix for you expression can look like

```
gsub("(B[0-1][0-9]|A[126]0mB[0-1][0-9])", "raster(\\1)", string)
```

Or even just matching 1 or more word chars (considering the sample string you supplied)

```
gsub("(\\w+)", "raster(\\1)", string)
```

might do.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/ZAGc5X).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explenation. I have some additional question in mind. Is it possible to use the replacement backreference in a vector or matrix like `gsub(regex,test[1,"\\1"],x))`, where test would be either of them?

Comment: @PhilG It is easiest  to use a [`gsubfn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) then, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450266/3832970).